# use YUI grid css style for partial page

Tags: css, yui

I have a menu bar in my page and I do not apply the YUI style for that. Below that, there are three doc sections I want to use YUI style. Example code:

```
<?php
include("style.html");
?>

<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.9.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/grids/grids-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css">

</head>
<body>
<div><h1>HEAD</h1></div>

<div id=top>TOP MENU</div> //top is defined in the included style html file

<div class="yui-gb">
  <div class="yui-u first">BODY PART</div>

.....
```

The part I use YUI is fine but the yui affects other div parts too. How can I solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grids should not be affecting other divs, but you appear to be loading reset-fonts-grids, the reset part of that would be affecting other divs. You also appear to be loading 3.9.0 YUI but CSS from version 2.x (2.9.0) I'd suggest avoiding crossing that barrier unless you *really* know why you want to.

There are reset, fonts, and grids CSS files for 3.9.0 too. In the case of using the 3.9.0 version you can use a contextual reset class to constrain the part of the page that it works against. To do so you want to load "cssreset-context/cssreset-context-min.css" and then add the "yui3-cssreset" class to the container that you want reset. This is documented here:

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/#context